# Autofill isn't working properly (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba, function, autofill

So I what I am trying to do is count the highlighted cells.

I have used the below function:

```
Function CountColorIf(rSample As Range, rArea As Range) As Long
Dim rAreaCell As Range
Dim lMatchColor As Long
Dim lCounter As Long

lMatchColor = rSample.Interior.Color
For Each rAreaCell In rArea
    If rAreaCell.Interior.Color = lMatchColor Then
        lCounter = lCounter + 1
    End If
Next rAreaCell
CountColorIf = lCounter
End Function
```

And then I put the below formula onto my starter cell:

```
Selection.Formula = "=CountColorIf(R" & ActiveCell.Row - 1 & "C,RC" & ActiveCell.Column - lcol + 2 & ":RC[-1])"
```

And finally I used the below autofill:

```
ActiveCell.AutoFill ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveCell.Address & ":" & Left(ActiveCell.Address, Len(ActiveCell.Address) - 1) & lRow)
```

While it's indeed copying the formula as I want the output I get in the cell is #VALUE!.

I have attached a picture of the result. I2 was my starter cell and there the cell result is fine. But the autofill result all appears as #value! although when I select the cell the formula is clearly there.

Any idea why that might be?[image]

Comment: What is the formula in `I2`?

Comment: =CountColorIf(I$1,$C2:H2)

Comment: Just wondering, but `Selection.Formula = "=CountColorIf(R" & ActiveCell.Row - 1 & "C,RC" & ActiveCell.Column - lcol + 2 & ":RC[-1])"`,.. the comma in `"C,RC"`.. shouldn't it be a `;`? Or in your system the separator is the comma?

Comment: The comma is the separator in my system.

Comment: Instead of using a starter cell and auto-filling, write the formula to the entire range (starter cell to last row) in one go.

Comment: tried your suggestion and it worked!
wonder why the auto-fill didn't though, maybe it's the function??

Comment: where is your code determining lcol and lrow?

Comment: @QHarr, at the beginning, this is part of a larger code. the lcol and lrow were fine as I used them in other instances as well.

Comment: About the Autofill Part, maybe you need first to use `Application.ReferenceStyle = xlR1C1`?